# Did an upvote-unupvote in the morning prevent me getting 200 rep on the rest of the day?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I'm puzzled that I got 205 points on the day rather than 215.  There was one accept, and enough other upvotes after the upvote-unupvote at 10:19 that I would have expected to score 215, not just 205.  Or is there something else going on that isn't showing up — but if there is, why isn't my rep tab telling me what is going on (I want to know).  I do have the 'show removed posts' box checked at the bottom of the page.

The three triangles at the top don't hide anything unexpected.  The first has two upvotes and an accept; the second has two upvotes; the third has a scoring upvote and a non-scoring upvote.

[image]

If the problem really is the upvote/unupvote, it means there's probably a denial-of-rep attack available to almost anyone, so in many ways, I hope there is something else going on.  But I'd like to know what, please.

Comment: Once you're beyond 30K it seems a bit pointless to worry about such a small rep change...

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare If there is a bug in the reputation calculations then reporting it is in the interest of those with lower rep too.

Comment: Plus, this post sounds less like "I WANT MY REP BACK!!!" than "Where did my rep go? I want to know everything."

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That upvote is included in the rep cap for that day, because it occurred that day.

The unupvote, however, actually retracts the 10 reputation from *some other day*. If you were rep capped on whatever day that upvote originally occurred, then another vote for that day would be adjusted to compensate for it whenever your reputation recalculated itself next.

I agree it's confusing, and I'd much rather it look [something like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes). If they were separated in such a way, the upvote would be grouped together with the rest of the votes you received that day, and the unupvote would be at the bottom under an "affects other days" bar, and not calculated into the day's total.

Comment: So I just got hit by two people in the same minute happening to upvote and unupvote one of my answers?  Long odds on that happening, isn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Someone had previously upvoted your post. They retracted their vote, which deletes the vote from whichever day they originally cast it, and then upvoted the post again, creating a *new* vote on that day. But for informational purposes, the reputation history displays both the retraction and the new vote on the same day.

Comment: Oh; so the sequence 'upvote' before 'unupvote' actually is the reverse of the order in which the events occurred?  The 'unupvote' happened first?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes. You can see the exact timestamp by hovering over the time. The unupvote happened 1 second before the upvote.

Comment: Grrr...OK; confusing presentation in multiple ways!  Thanks.  Someone needs another 'order by' in the data collection.

Comment: The current behavior of the list is that it sorts by net reputation gain for the group, and then sorts the group (and the individual events within it) by time, newest-first.

Comment: Then a denial-of-rep attack: 20 bots upvote you, then toggle the upvote every day. They have to give you 200 rep initially though.

Comment: @jing though they would also need to make an edit to the posts every day as the vote would be locked in.

Comment: @jingyu That wouldn't do anything. If you had other votes, then those votes would start counting as the bot votes were being invalidated. All the bots would be doing is moving the reputation they gave from day to day. No attack possible here.