# How does unupvote work again?

Tags: support, voting

I'm trying to understand how unupvoting works and its potential consequences. I know that [an upupvote means someone just retracted a former upvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251802/3681880), something that is possible because the post was edited and the vote lock removed. Sometimes people unupvote and reupvote in quick succession.

I've read these posts but I still don't understand how the system works:

- [Did an upvote-unupvote in the morning prevent me getting 200 rep on the rest of the day?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308547/did-an-upvote-unupvote-in-the-morning-prevent-me-getting-200-rep-on-the-rest-of)
- [Why did this unupvote/upvote result in a gain of +10 reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302182/why-did-this-unupvote-upvote-result-in-a-gain-of-10-reputation)

Where are the votes coming from and going to in the following situations:

### Situation A

Day 1:

- Bobbie upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 100.

Day 2:

- Bobbie unupvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 90? (10 new upvotes, 1 unupvote)

### Situation B

Day 1:

- Bobbie upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 100.

Day 2:

- Bobbie unupvoted my post and re-upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 100. (10 new upvotes, 1 unupvote, 1 re-upvote)

### Situation C

Day 1:

- Bobbie upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 200. (25 upvotes and rep capped at 200)

Day 2:

- Bobbie unupvoted my post and re-upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 100? (10 new upvotes, 1 unupvote, 1 re-upvote)

### Situation D

Day 1:

- Bobbie upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 200. (25 upvotes and rep capped at 200)

Day 2:

- Bobbie unupvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 90? (10 new upvotes, 1 unupvote)

### Situation E

Day 1:

- Bobbie upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 100.

Day 2:

- Bobbie unupvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 190? (25 new upvotes, 1 unupvote)

### Situation F

Day 1:

- Bobbie upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 100.

Day 2:

- Bobbie unupvoted my post and re-upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 190? (25 new upvotes, 1 unupvote, 1 re-upvote)

### Situation G

Day 1:

- Bobbie upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 200. (25 upvotes)

Day 2:

- Bobbie unupvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 200? (25 new upvotes, 1 unupvote)

### Situation H

Day 1:

- Bobbie upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 200. (25 upvotes)

Day 2:

- Bobbie unupvoted my post and re-upvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 200? (25 new upvotes, 1 unupvote, 1 re-upvote)

### Situation I

Day 1:

- Bobbie upvoted my post and then unupvoted my post.
- My total daily score is 90? (10 new upvotes, 1 unupvote)

### Situation J

Day 1:

- Bobbie upvoted my post and then unupvoted my post *before* I hit the rep cap.
- My total daily score is 190? (25 new upvotes, 1 unupvote)

### Situation K

Day 1:

- Bobbie upvoted my post and then unupvoted my post *after* I hit the rep cap.
- My total daily score is 200? (25 new upvotes, 1 unupvote)

## Question

Which day are the points coming from and going to? I just know that I occasionally see what looks like a rep cap at 190.

## Consequences

Could a devious user lower someone's rep cap just by upvoting and then unupvoting a few of their answers?

Comment: I scrolled down fast to see what notation you used after Situation Z, disappointed. :(

Comment: If you got to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation, there never is a -10 or -15 for unupvotes or unaccepts.

Comment: @muru, that makes sense in light of Martijn Pieters' answer. It was as if the vote never occurred. So that is how it works for unaccept, too? It is as if the answer was never accepted?

Comment: @Suragch best I can tell, yes. For example, I had an answer unaccepted on U&L on Feb 23, but the corresponding entry in /reputation shows no changes, and on the day on which it was accepted, Feb 20, no accepts are shown.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's a **long** list of scenarios, I'm not going to cover each one in detail.

Basically, **re-calculate** your score for the day the original vote was cast on, **without that vote**. It is gone from that day, *as if if was never cast*. This means you re-apply any capping rules, etc.

Then do the same for the day where the vote was *re-cast* (if it was re-cast), it as an *entirely new, independent vote*. You got a vote on that day, it counts towards the cap, etc.

The 'un-upvote' entry in your reputation history is only there to help you understand the history of the votes (to answer the question *why did I lose a vote for that post* questions).

You want to look at your *reputation audit log* at `https://stackoverflow.com/reputation` to see the actual reputation accounting. The reputation changes you see in your *reputation history tab* reflect the reputation loss for the un-upvote on the day that it took place however, as if the actual recalculation can't go back in time to correct the record.

Note that the rep cap can't be lowered by un-upvoting; your history is just re-calculated including the actual caps.

Comment: This is the generalized answer I was looking for. I think I understand it enough now to know what all of the scenarios would be. Thanks.